# Why does ts-node think it has a src directory, if when I look in node_modules there is none?

Tags: npm, node-modules, ts-node

I am running my project using `ts-node` and I get the following error

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
spec/crons/dailyjob.spec.ts(51,9): error TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.

    at createTSError (C:\Users\joe\Documents\projects\client1\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:820:12)
    at reportTSError (C:\Users\joe\Documents\projects\client2\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:824:19)
....
```

I am curious what is going on, so I want to set a breakpoint at `index.ts`. But when I look in the `ts-node` directory, there no such `src` directory. It doesn't exist. Yet the script thinks it is running code from there.

Where is it?

[ts-node directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InUkN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running a distribution version of the ts-node module, not its development source code. The paths being logged are being mapped from the distribution files you're using to their original source paths which need not exist on your machine.

As you can see on this attached picture, the file `node_modules/ts-node/dist/index.js.map` tells you that the file `index.js` maps to `../src/index.ts` before build, which is the path that gets logged to the end-user of the module.

[index.js.map excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejRfL.png)

These files are remapped because the stack traces of the module are meant to aid the developers of the module debug their builds, not the projects that use it.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't realize the error messages use the map to the sourrce. Thanks